# SSIS - Flat File Destination data formatting

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

If I have a column of type DT_DBDATE or DT_DBTIMESTAMP, and I write the data to a file using a Flat File Destination component, the resulting date formatting will YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I've experimented with changing the package locale and changing the datatype in the Flat File Connection Manager, but these don't seem to have any effect.

What determines this format and is there any way I can change the default formatting?

PS. I know I can use Data Conversion and Derived Column components to change the data types/formats. The point is we have +150 packages and get too many errors when someone forgets to do the conversion or does it incorrectly.

We're using SSIS 2012.

Comment: So, which format do you need? And what are the flatfiles used for? If they are processed by some other task / package, it might be worth considering to change the reading process instead of the writing process...

Comment: The format I need is YYYY-MMM-DD. The flat files are used by another process over which I have no control. If I did, I would have done what you suggested.

Comment: And DT_DBDATE results in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS as well??

Comment: Personally, I would handle this with a CONVERT function in the source SQL query.

Comment: The source is Oracle DATE column which Attunity maps to DT_DBTIMESTAMP. I would like to retain the data as a date or a timestamp within SSIS in case we need to do date-based processing. I guess the root of the problem is that Oracle doesn't have a date-only type. CONVERT doesn't help as Attunity would still map it to DT_DBTIMESTAMP. Looks like Data Conversion is our only option. Loss of data is not an issue as our Oracle dates don't contain the time component. SSIS formats DT_DATE as M/D/YYYY so converting the dates still doesn't fully resolve the issue.

Comment: Too many errors when someone forgets to do the conversion or does it incorrectly points to a change in process All SSIS packages should l be code reviewed (we code review 100% of all our code including SSIS packages and have a checklist for them to make sure logging is correct and things like this) and one of the points in the review should be to look specifically for this.

Comment: @HLGEM True. And Flat File Destination component having hard-coded formatting points to a shortcoming in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using SSIS 2008 with SQL Server 2008 R2. If you are trying to generate a CSV file, I would recommend first, at the database level, to store the value in the desired format. This means, for instance, if you want to display a column where the current date is in the format YYYY-MM-DD, then you should use the appropriate code to store that value. Using T-SQL will be: *convert(varchar(10), cast(GETDATE() as date), 126)*. Double check that the value was stored in the desired format by reading the table. Now it comes the tricky part: no matter what you are using in SSIS for transforming the dates, if you open the CSV using Excel, then Excel is going to display the dates using the format was set for the operating system. Don't panic, just don't save that file when you want to close it. Instead, if you open the CSV using Notepad or Notepad++, you should be able to see the date columns right in the format you used for storing them in the database.

Comment: We use Oracle. When pulling data from Oracle columns of type DATE get mapped to DT_DBTIMESTAMP in SSIS. Doing what you suggest would result in me having dates of type DT_STR in SSIS. This would prevent me from doing any date-based manipulation on the SSIS side (or I would have to convert to DT_DATE again). Based on the lack of answers to my question, it would seem that SSIS Flat File Destination used hard-coded formats, one of many shortcomings of SSIS.